# Why is the console closed after first step?

Tags: c#

```
var books = new List<Book>(3);  

foreach (Book item in books)
{               
    item.Title = Console.ReadLine();
    item.Countofpage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                
}
```

When I enter the title into the console, my program just closes.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the list with the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-ctor(system-int32)) that sets the capacity of the list. But this will not do what you expect. A list uses an array as collection which will be re-created with the double-size if the item count exceeds the capacity. So this constructor can be used to optimize it, because the array can be correctly sized at the beginning.

But **the list is still empty** no matter what capacity you use.

So you can use a `for-loop`:

```
int capacity = 3;
var books = new List<Book>( capacity );  
for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
     Book book = new Book();
     book.Title = Console.ReadLine();
     book.Countofpage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // use int.TryParse
     books.Add(book);
}
```

Side-note: don't confuse it with a array, where you really get the size:

```
Book[] books  = new Book[capacity]; // contains 3 books which are all null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create list and fill items of it. You can look through blow example. Before that I want to mention a few points. In C#, capacity of List is defined explicitly, of course you can set capacity but it's not mandatory.

```
var books = new List<Book>();
var booksCount = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Enter book's count:");
booksCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < booksCount; i++)
{
    books.Add(
        new Book()
        {
            Title = Console.ReadLine(),
            Countofpage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
        });
}

foreach (var book in books)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Book title: {book.Title}, page count:{book.Countofpage}");
}
```